# Set-theoretic Properties of a Universe

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

I would like to show that if {$A_{i}$: i$\in$I} $\subseteq$ $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{U}$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I}$$A_{i}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{U}$, where $\mathbb{U}$ is a *universe* and the capital $A's$ are all sets (p. 162-163, Lectures on the Hyperreals, William Goldberg).

A *universe* is a *strongly transitive* set $\mathbb{U}$ such that:

1) if $a,b\in\mathbb{U}$, then ${a,b}\in\mathbb{U}$

2) if there are sets $A,B\in\mathbb{U}$, then $A\cup{B}\in\mathbb{U}$.

3) if there is a set $A\in\mathbb{U}$, then $\mathcal{P}(A)\in\mathbb{U}$

**Strong Transitivity:**  for any set $A\in\mathbb{U}$, there exists a transitive set $B\in\mathbb{U}$ with $A\subseteq{B}\subseteq{\mathbb{U}}$. *Transitivity of $B$* means that $c\in{C}\in{B}\implies{c\in{B}}$

Comment: Could you clarify what "universe" is for you?

Comment: I'll quote the author: "In... analyzing a particular structure, access may be needed to a wide range of entities: sets, members of sets, sequences, relations, functions, etc.  We will posit the existence of a "universe" U that contains all such entities that might be required."  Furthermore, such a U will be a called "universe over X" if X  is a set that is an element of U and the members of X are regarded as individuals that are not sets and have no members themselves.  U will contain at least one set and also the positive integers 1,2,... to ensure that m-tuple formation can be carried out.